# Late binding to an event raised by a dynamic control - event does not fire

Tags: c#, dynamic, binding

I have tried without success to follow the code given here and on other forums.  I just cannot get the event to fire.

The same control added manually to the form works fine...it raises the event and the parent form consumes it.  So the control is capable of working, just not in the way I am (so far) trying to do it with Reflection.

I have a small DEMO of the web application available for download here:

http://ube.dev.campuswebstore.mobi/dloadfile.htm

Here is the code and I will comment where I am trying to link the event to the handler (the part which is not working):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        TestRaiseEvent77.ButtonClickEvent += new ButtonWasClicked(TestRaiseEvent77_ButtonClickEvent);

        string layout = "";

        if (Request.QueryString["layout"] != null)
        {
            layout = Request.QueryString["layout"] as string;
        }
        else
        {
            layout = "default";
        }


        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GlobalMethods.InitControlList();
            LoadControls(layout);
            AddControlsFromList();
            WireControlEventsToHandlers();
        }
        else
        {
            AddControlsFromList();
            WireControlEventsToHandlers();
        }
    }

    void TestRaiseEvent77_ButtonClickEvent(string message)
    {

    }



    private void AddControlsFromList()
    {

        sitemanagercontrolsdiv.Controls.Clear();

        try
        {
            if (GlobalMethods.divlayoutgencontrols != null)
            {
                foreach (Control c in GlobalMethods.divlayoutgencontrols)
                {
                    sitemanagercontrolsdiv.Controls.Add(c);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception eee)
        {
            string a = eee.Message;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



    }
```

//NOTES:

```
    //The control collection cannot be modified during 
    //DataBind, 
    //Init, 
    //Load, 
    //PreRender or 
    //Unload phases.


    private void WireControlEventsToHandlers()
    {
        foreach (Control c in sitemanagercontrolsdiv.Controls)
        {                
            Type controlType = c.GetType();

            BindingFlags myBindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
            EventInfo[] myEvents = controlType.GetEvents(myBindingFlags);

            for (int j = 0; j < myEvents.Count(); j++)
            {
                string eventName = myEvents.ElementAt(j).Name;
                if (eventName == "ButtonClickedEvent")
                {
                    MethodInfo handler = typeof(_Default).GetMethod("SomeHandler");
                    Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(myEvents.ElementAt(j).EventHandlerType, this, handler);
```

//////////////////////////////// WHATEVER THIS IS DOING IT IS NOT WORKING

```
                    myEvents.ElementAt(j).AddEventHandler(c, del);
                }
            }

            c.Visible = true;
            string tempGUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            c.ID = "TestRaiseEvent" + tempGUID + "1";
        }

    }

    private void LoadControls(string layout)
    {
        Control c = LoadControl("~/TestRaiseEvent.ascx");

        GlobalMethods.divlayoutgencontrols.Add(c);
    }
```

//////////////////  I AM TRYING TO LINK THE EVENT TO THIS HANDLER:

```
    public void SomeHandler(string message)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My brother-in-law gave me the answer last night.  Just a few minor changes having to deal with the ID of the control.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WebApplication2
{
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string layout = "";

        if (Request.QueryString["layout"] != null)
        {
            layout = Request.QueryString["layout"] as string;
        }
        else
        {
            layout = "default";
        }


        //if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
        GlobalMethods.InitControlList();
        LoadControls(layout);
        //}

    }

    private void AddControlsFromList()
    {

        sitemanagercontrolsdiv.Controls.Clear();

        try
        {
            if (GlobalMethods.divlayoutgencontrols != null)
            {
                foreach (Control c in GlobalMethods.divlayoutgencontrols)
                {
                    sitemanagercontrolsdiv.Controls.Add(c);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception eee)
        {
            string a = eee.Message;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddControlsFromList();
    }


    //The control collection cannot be modified during 
    //DataBind, 
    //Init, 
    //Load, 
    //PreRender or 
    //Unload phases.

    protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //AddControlsFromList();
    }

    private void LoadControls(string layout)
    {
        Control c = LoadControl("~/TestRaiseEvent.ascx");

        Type controlType = c.GetType();

        BindingFlags myBindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
        EventInfo[] myEvents = controlType.GetEvents(myBindingFlags);

        for (int j = 0; j < myEvents.Count(); j++)
        {
            string eventName = myEvents.ElementAt(j).Name;
            if (eventName == "ButtonClickEvent")
            {
                MethodInfo handler = typeof(_Default).GetMethod("SomeHandler");
                Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(myEvents.ElementAt(j).EventHandlerType, this, handler);
                myEvents.ElementAt(j).AddEventHandler(c, del);
            }
        }

        c.Visible = true;
        //string tempGUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        //c.ID = "TestRaiseEvent" + tempGUID + "1";
        c.ID = "TestRaiseEvent1";

        GlobalMethods.divlayoutgencontrols.Add(c);
    }


    public void SomeHandler(string message)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

}